# Update multiple fields in mongoose subdocuments using $push

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a conversation schema which will contain two users. I want to flag messages to be deleted from one user so the other recipient still able to read the message.

**Schema**

```
// Messages Schema
var messagesSchema = new Schema({
    from: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User',
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },

    deleted_by: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }],

    read_by: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }],

}, {
    timestamps: true
});

// Conversation Schema
var conversationsSchema = new Schema({

    recipients: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User',
        index: true
    }],

    messages: [messagesSchema],

}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Now when I create a conversation between two users it will look like the following

```
[
  {
    "_id": "57bb6fed3d001f054e809175",
    "updatedAt": "2016-08-22T21:37:30.631Z",
    "createdAt": "2016-08-22T21:34:37.381Z",
    "__v": 2,
    "messages": [
      {
        "updatedAt": "2016-08-22T21:34:37.380Z",
        "createdAt": "2016-08-22T21:34:37.380Z",
        "from": "57b7448668d04d3035774b9a",
        "content": "Hello are you there?",
        "_id": "57bb6fed3d001f054e809176",
        "read_by": [],
        "deleted_by": []
      },
      {
        "updatedAt": "2016-08-22T21:34:58.060Z",
        "createdAt": "2016-08-22T21:34:58.060Z",
        "from": "57b7448668d04d3035774b9a",
        "content": "I miss you",
        "_id": "57bb70023d001f054e809177",
        "read_by": [],
        "deleted_by": []
      },
      {
        "updatedAt": "2016-08-22T21:37:30.631Z",
        "createdAt": "2016-08-22T21:37:30.631Z",
        "from": "57b7816b68d04d3035774b9b",
        "content": "Hey... Me too",
        "_id": "57bb709a3d001f054e809178",
        "read_by": [],
        "deleted_by": []
      }
    ],
    "recipients": [
      "57b7448668d04d3035774b9a",
      "57b7816b68d04d3035774b9b"
    ]
  }
]
```

Now when one of the users want to delete the conversation from his side I want to add the user id to the `deleted_by` array inside each message.

I am trying to do something like this

```
Conversation.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: conversation_id
}, {
    $push: {
        'messages.deleted_by': req.loggedInUser._id
    }
}, function(err, data) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.json(data);
})
```

**Error Returned**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$isMongooseDocumentArray' of undefined
```

I tried to add the `$` sign and still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Conversation.findOne({
    _id: conversation_id
}, function(err, docs) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    if(docs)
    {
        docs.messages.forEach(function(msg,index,array)
        {
            msg.deleted_by.push(req.loggedInUser._id);
        });
        docs.save();
    }
});
```

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for better understanding of forEach function.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> You can push multiple items just by adding the parameters in the $push field
> Example: `$push:{<field1>:<value1>,<field2>:<value2>}`

```
Conversation.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: conversation_id}, 
    {$push: {messages.deleted_by: req.loggedInUser._id,read_by: //your_fields }
    }, function(err, data) {
        if(err) return next(err);
            res.json(data);
 })
```