# Could not use $push on mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I tried to update the document, the following error occurs

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$isMongooseDocumentArray' of undefined
```

Model and Update is as follows,

Model

```
const LiveSchema = new Schema({
  data: Schema.Types.Mixed,
  type: String
},{
  timestamps:true
});

const Live = mongoose.model('Live', LiveSchema);
```

Update

```
....
  .then((source) => {
      return Live.update({"data.source.id":id},{$push:{'data.source': source}},{upsert:true}).lean().exec();
 });
```

But when I tried the similar query on mongo shell as follows, it worked fine.

```
 db.lives.update({'data.source.id':"7464a019-b667-4c9d-b2263846b78fd49e"},{$push:{'data.source':{'test':'lorem'} }});
```

The result was

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update multiple fields in mongoose subdocuments using $push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090421/update-multiple-fields-in-mongoose-subdocuments-using-push)

Comment: Why `.lean()` ? It is used in read-only scenarios, and returns pure JSON instead of entire Mongoose objects. Therefore it can't have `update` method or anything. It could be the reason of your problem.